# Tomcat is taking too much of time to start for my Eclipse Web application when the Port 8081 forwarded in my WLAN router

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, port, router, forwarding

We have forwarded the port 8081 in our WLAN router for a particular Static IP address. After that, tomcat is taking too much of time to start. Approximately, it is taking 56149 ms to run. Why it's happening so? Do I need to add any exceptions in my firewall? Is there any way to start it faster.

Any idea would be greatly appreciable!!!

Comment: what does tomcat have to do with this port 8081? tomcat couldn't care less what ports you've forwarded, unless you're using tomcat for/on those ports.

Comment: But, tomcat is taking too much of time to start when connected with WLAN router

Comment: It doesn't work like that. You're forwarding the port, and that's all on the router's side. As far as Tomcat knows it's just listening on its own machine's interface, as usual. Did it launch faster before? Did anything else change?

Comment: Yes. Before, it started in 13s. Now it starts in 56s.